# App shortcut (custom by private)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

[image]

Hi there

I tried to put in App Short customed by me, But it's not working at all
weirdly if I put function key on other shortcuts (such as Show notification center )
It super work well

How Can I open the Email app just by pressing the f1 key? (already set as standard function key)

Comment: Also note: The Help menu in Apple apps & preference panes actually does help. [This is often comes as a surprise to ex-Windows users, for which it usually contains little but an 'about' notice]

Answer (score 1):

You are using that feature totally wrong! The *menu command* is not the *top level menu name*, its what's under the *top level menu name* that are *commands* Please have a look at: [Create keyboard shortcuts for apps on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac)

That said, this is not even the right place to create a *keyboard shortcut* that opens an *application*. As an example, you can create a *Quick Action/Service* in **Automator** and open an *application*, then assign it a *keyboard shortcut* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, not: ... **App Shortcuts**

There are several *third-party application* that *keyboard shortcuts* can be assigned to programmed actions and any one of them may be better than using an **Automator**  *Quick Action/Service*. For example I use [**FastScripts**](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/) and [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org) to assign *keyboard shortcuts* that in turn when pressed run **AppleScript** *scripts*, *shell scripts*, **Lua** *code*, etc. to accomplish all sorts of tasks. For example, in **FastScripts** I press **F6** to empty the **Trash** without prompting. This is because the **F6** *key* is not assigned to anything else on my system, so with nothing to conflict with it, it just works.

FWIW Using a single *key* as a *keyboard shortcut* can be problematic and generally speaking (IMO) should not be done. Also, depending on other *system preferences* pressing the **fn** *key* may also be necessary, as by default pressing **F1** adjusts the brightness of the screen.

If you keep the **Mail** icon in the **Dock** you can a open it with a *single-click* vs. a *single-keypress*.

---

As previously mentioned about other *system preferences*, in e.g. **macOS Catalina** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** one must check the **[√] Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys** *checkbox* to use the *function keys* as *standard function keys* and with that checked and with the following snippet of **Lua** *code* in **Hammerspoon** it opens **Mail**, or if its already open it *focuses* it. Otherwise I'd also have to press **fn** with **F1**:

```lua
hs.hotkey.bind({}, "f1", function()
    hs.application.launchOrFocus("Mail") 
end)
```

---

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated with the developers of the aforementioned *third-party applications*, just a satisfied user of the products.</sub>